# Tridion 2013 SP1 CME slowness?

Tags: 2013-sp1, logging

Do we have any bench marks for time duration of basic activities we perform in Tridion CME like Page or Component save and Preview and Publish consider I am creating Page or Components in DXA Example website. How to identify the bottle necks I looked the `Tridion.contentmanager.log` no helpful information available.

Comment: Network analysis tools (wireshark, fiddler) are probably your best friends here. Check the calls to what methods, the size of the responses, the delays, etc. Might help identify the bottleneck.

Comment: is it for any specific component or overall?

Comment: I am looking Overall, not specific to any component, For example if Component Save is taking 16 sec, Is it Idle time or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no bench mark times listed for any of the actions anywhere, since performance is related to a large set of parameters which include implementation specifics, hardware, etc.

However what I noted in the past 14 years of working with SDL Tridion is that bad performance on a CM server is generally releated to poor database performance, which is usually related to a failure to perform database maintenance.

SDL Tridion is a high transaction volume system, which means it is very important to reguraly update the statistics of the CM database. While on production environments this does seem to happen (with a properly configured maintenance plan including a backup strategy), it is often forgotten/ignored on development and test environments.

The first thing I always do when a CM server is slow is update the statistics of the CM database and that usually gives me a huge performance increase (showing it wasn't done for a while). On a MS SQL server database you can simply run the stored procedure: `exec sp_updatestats;` on Oracle, check with a DBA and ask him how to update the statistics, or check out the documentation.

Comment: Thank you Bart, We are not executing Maintenance scripts provided by Tridion, I will work with my DBA and execute maintenance scripts post the update.

Answer (score 1):

Bart's answer is correct 99% of the time, do that first.
If you still have performance problems then throttled disk IOPS can also kill performance. I came across this problem a four years ago when installing CMS on Azure and Hyper-V.